# Dynamically included JSP does not resolve JSP tags?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, taglib

We are migrating and had issues because of servlet methods exceeding 65535 bytes.

I tried to split the code and use dynamic include instead of static ones, i.e., I've replaced `<%@ include file="some.js" %>` with `<jsp:include path="some.js">`.

The page compiles but unfortunately now all the `<%= request.xxx %>` values are *not resovled* in the output JSP, and I see them in the HTML code.

Any hints how to make them interpreted?

Comment: Try to set content type in that.

Comment: Shouldn't the files be named `some.jsp` instead of `some.js`? IMHO Tomcat (by default) does not know it should compile and execute the `.js` files as JSP. Also, having issues because methods exceed 65535 bytes calls for some serious refactoring, but I am sure you're aware of it.